# Survival trees with competing risk

Tags: r, survival, cart, competing-risks

I'm looking for a way to fit survival trees with competing risk.

Can I use the function `LTRCART` in the [LTRCtrees](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LTRCtrees/vignettes/LTRCtrees.html) package in R to fit a survival tree using the dataset obtained from the `finegray` function in [survival](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) R package.

Here a reproducible example using `mgus2` data in `survival` package:

```
library(survival)
data("mgus2")

etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))

ds_finegray <- finegray(Surv(etime, event) ~  age + sex + mspike,
data = mgus2, etype = "pcm")

library(LTRCtrees)

survTree_LTRC <- LTRCART(Surv(fgstart,fgstop, fgstatus) ~ age + sex + mspike, 
data = ds_finegray, weights = ds_finegray$fgweights)

survTree_LTRC

library(partykit)
survTree_LTRC_party <- as.party(survTree_LTRC)
survTree_LTRC_party$fitted[["(response)"]] <- 
Surv(ds_finegray$fgstart, ds_finegray$fgstop, ds_finegray$fgstatus)
plot(survTree_LTRC_party)
```

A shown in the example there are no issues with the `R` programming.  My question is about the consistency of the split method used in the `rpart`function. This uses a splitting criterion based on a node deviance measure between a saturated model log–likelihood and a maximized log–likelihood, approximating the full likelihood by replacing the baseline cumulative hazard function by the Nelson–Aalen estimator (8.4 section in [rpart vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf)).

Since `finegray` applies a Fine-Gray model to competing risk (multi-state) data, giving as result a dataset with interval censoring time and weights <1 for observations with competing events, I'm not able to understand whether the assumption made by the `rpart` routine are still valid for this kind of data.

Comment: There is a risk this might be closed as off-topic as you seem to be asking for R help. There does seem to be a possible statistical issue here about fitting trees when you have competing risks - is it possible? Perhaps edit your question to stress the statistical part?

Comment: I submitted a question on this topic in asked this question at r-help@r-project.org (see R-help Digest, Vol 182, Issue 25) on April 25 2018:
"Dear all,
I'm interested in fitting survival trees with competing risk analysis.
The tree should show the cumulative incidence function for each terminal node I read several paper illustrating this possibility, but to the best of my knowledge no R code are reported.
There is any R package for this fit?
Thank you very much in advance."
However, at this time the query remained unanswered. Any progress on this interesting topic? Mario Petretta